# Active admin redirect to_back doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Why my `redirect_to :back` doesn't work? it just redirect to the same page.

my method

```
controller do

      def update
      update! do |success, failure|
        success.html { redirect_to :back }
      end
    end

  end
```

my `request.referer`returns me my current path

Answer (score 3):

I had good success in my use case `url_for(:back)`. I specifically used it like this, but I would guess it works in other places

```
form do |f|
  f.actions do
    f.action :submit
    f.cancel_link(url_for(:back))
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that the following works:

`redirect_backwards_or_to_root`

https://www.rubydoc.info/github/gregbell/active_admin/ActiveAdmin%2FBaseController%2FAuthorization:redirect_backwards_or_to_root

Rails 6, ActiveAdmin 2.7

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old. I was trying to solve the same issue. And found the way to do it. So I share it here.

Based on this code in [here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/4b49319751b8c58363f46ae1d99e5bb1b7b65c39/lib/active_admin/orm/active_record/comments.rb#LC53)

This is how we do redirect back in ActiveAdmin

`ActiveAdmin::Dependency.rails.redirect_back self, active_admin_root`

Hope that help.